# Eclipse is not stopping/breaking at breakpoint?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, breakpoints

I am trying to put breakpoints in my code for some simple debugging but my program is not stopping or telling me if the breakpoints is reached. I use CRTL+SHIFT+B and the breakpoint is visible in blue (enabled) on the left side. I am using these breakpoints in my core project and running from desktop project. Am i missing something and/or how to fix this?

Comment: It could simply mean that the code does not reach the line where the breakpoint is. Try to put a breakpoint earlier.

Comment: Check if the breakpoint is actually present in the Breakpoints view in Eclipse to confirm. Otherwise it should mean the code did not reach the line.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, of course i put the breakpoint at the very first line that i am sure that the code is reaching. Also the breakpoint is showing in the breakpoints window.

Comment: Is it normal Java project debugging  or remote java application?.Hope the debug port is not being utilised by any other application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the

```
Menu -> Run -> Skip All Breakpoints
```

to see if it was checked?  I ran into this once and it drove me crazy as well.

Comment: Whoops, how did that turn on?